# Python lmza.LMZADecompressor() returning null byte

Tags: python-3.x, lzma

i compressed the bytes and when i tried to decompress it gives a null byte.

```
import lzma
comp = lzma.LZMACompressor()
decomp = lzma.LZMADecompressor()
a= comp.compress(b'alpha')
print(a)
b = decomp.decompress(a)
print(b)
```

this the results.

```
b'\xfd7zXZ\x00\x00\x04\xe6\xd6\xb4F\x02\x00!\x01\x16\x00\x00\x00t/\xe5\xa3'
b''
```

why is this occuring and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `comp.compress` doesn't return the complete compressed bytestring.
You have to append the result of `comp.flush()` to `a`.

```
import lzma
comp = lzma.LZMACompressor()
decomp = lzma.LZMADecompressor()
a= comp.compress(b'alpha') + comp.flush()
print(a)
b = decomp.decompress(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: that's funny because in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/lzma.py#L319) is already done, `comp.compress(data) + comp.flush()`. It seems a further _explicit_ call is needed